# Nested Form Update in Rails 3 sets foreign key as NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, formtastic

I am trying to update a user record using a formtastic nested form. Its structure is as ollows

```
User 
   Admin
   Address
```

When I send the form to update details, while updating the address or admin record, the user_id(foreign key) gets set to NULL. This is the data that gets sent and it seems to be ok.

```
Parameters: {
             "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"some token", 
             "user"=>{
                 "id"=>"16",
                 "first_name"=>"User", 
                 "last_name"=>"Name", 
                 "email"=>"username@gmail.com", 
                 "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
                 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
                 "address_attributes"=>{
                      "main_phone"=>"131231233", 
                      "address1"=>"Address 1 Line", 
                      "address2"=>"Address 2 Line", 
                      "city"=>"Lansing",  
                      "state"=>"Michigan", 
                      "zip"=>"48823", 
                      "user_id"=>"16"
                 }, 
                 "admin_attributes"=>{
                      "company_id"=>"2", 
                      "user_id"=>"16"
                 }, 
                 "roles_mask"=>"1", 
                 "user_id"=>"16"
                 }, 
                 "commit"=>"Update User Roles", 
                 "company_id"=>"2", 
                 "id"=>"16"
           }
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
  has_one :admin, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user      
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :roles_mask, :terms_of_use,:id
  attr_accessible :owner_attributes, :admin_attributes, :address_attributes, :client_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, :admin, :client, :address  
end
```

**Admin Model**

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :admin

  attr_accessible :company_id, :user_id
end
```

**Address Model*

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :address


  attr_accessible :address1, :user_id, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :main_phone, :cell_phone
end
```

Could you please help me with this. Thanks.

**UPDATED with the model details. I removed the validation to keep it short.**

Comment: Add your User and Admin model sources to your question pls.

Comment: @Hck, updated the question with the model details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to correct

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, :admin, :client, :address
```

in your User model with

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner, :client
accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin, :address, :update_only => true
```